# ¿Permiso denegado c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

> x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe cannot open output file C:\Codigos\C++\factorial.exe: Permission denied
> C:\Codigos\C++\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Antes de este error ya sabia por que ocurría y es por que el .exe ya se está ejecutando pero después de revisar el administrador de tareas y apagar mi computados 2-3 veces me empecé a preocupar ya que solo estaba sucediendo con ese archivo

Me imagino que o es un error diferente al que estoy planteando o es un problema que no me permite visualizar el programa en el administrador de tareas

Comment: Puedes borrar o mover el archivo factorial.exe? para ver si ld.exe puede crearlo nuevamente

Comment: Si, lo intente pero igual daba el error lo intentaré en otro archivo y voy a ignorar lo que sucedió